# Mesh modeling and shad smooth results

Tags: modeling, mesh

This is a sword pommel I am modeling.  Last part of the sword and it will be done as my fist modeling test in blender.

As you can see I tried my best to keep the mesh as simple as possible.  In order to have a good smooth result.
[image]

[image]

Then why am I getting this when I add a simple smooth shade?
[image]

If I try a multiresolution, subdivide or smooth modifiers it is even worse with the whole mesh messing up terribly the more I add on the modifiers.  WHY?

I have a file upload here for you to check.  It is the pomel and the crossguard of the sword on which both I used a mirror modifier.  Guessing is the source fo the problem.
[image]

**I think I have solved the problem by first perfecting the mesh a bit then cutting the mesh in half on the side which best was effected by the shade smooth and added a mirror modifier.**  Still, I would love to understand normals a bit more especially what is the difference between the red and blue?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). You can also [upload your file here](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a look.

Comment: I forgot I could upload the file.  What a noob!  I have a file upload here for you to check. It is the pommel and the crossguard of the sword on which both I used a mirror modifier.  THANKS

Comment: Hello :). I checked your file and edited my answer. I also added and explanation of what *Normals* are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mesh has some modeling issues :).
I'll talk only about your *Pommel object* here.

**01) Lots of N-gons**
*N-gons* (faces with more than 4 sides) don't work well with shading or Subdivision modifier.
It's better to use quads and tris.

*You original mesh left, repaired right*
[image]

**02) Overlapping geometry**
This is a big problem in 3D modelling.
You have double edges, vertices and faces.
Some can be cleaned up by *Mesh->Clean up->Merge by distance*, but others have to be cleaned manually.

[image]

**03) Flipped normals**
Normals show which way a polygon is facing. If they're not facing the same way, it causes problems with shading and Subdivision.

You can check your normals here.
Blue should be facing out, red should be facing in.
[image]

To fix all, select your whole mesh and go to *Mesh->Normals->Recalculate outside*.
[image]

**Additional issues:**
Your *origin point* isn't in the center - it's a tiny bit to the side.
This causes problems with the Mirror modifier.

**Other tips for your workflow:**
Set your units to milimeters for better precision.
Use orthographic view - it will help you be more precise.
Enable absolute grid snap - it will snap precisely to your grid.
Mirror modifier has a *Clipping option* - use it.

[image]

You're doing great so far, don't feel discouraged.
Good luck with your model, you're on the right track :).

Here is the repaired file:
[image]

Comment: I need to learn more on Normals since I seem to encounter this problem a lot and I still cannot understand.  I tried both your suggested solutions  Reculclate outside [link](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=9901043736FBFBA5&id=9901043736FBFBA5%2111916&parId=9901043736FBFBA5%219325&o=OneUp) but the result is still the same.

Comment: Thanks very Jachym your explanation was great.  I will try to correct my models as per your suggestions to see if I can manage it up and thanks for correcting it as well.